# Combing pandas dataframes that have overlapping columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that can be created using the following code:

```
import yfinance as yf

symbols = ['QQQ', 'GBTC']
df1 = yf.download(symbols, start="2019-01-01", end="2019-01-07")

symbols = ['GBTC', 'TLT']
df2 = yf.download(symbols, start="2019-01-01", end="2019-01-07")
```

The contents of `df1` and `df2` are as the following

```
> df1
           Adj Close              Close              High               Low  \
                GBTC         QQQ   GBTC         QQQ  GBTC         QQQ  GBTC   
Date                                                                          
2018-12-31     3.965  152.132996  3.965  154.259995  4.15  154.979996  3.95   
2019-01-02     4.620  152.744461  4.620  154.880005  4.65  155.750000  4.13   
2019-01-03     4.520  147.754257  4.520  149.820007  4.62  153.259995  4.32   
2019-01-04     4.530  154.075851  4.530  156.229996  4.65  157.000000  4.41   

                         Open               Volume            
                   QQQ   GBTC         QQQ     GBTC       QQQ  
Date                                                          
2018-12-31  152.710007  4.140  154.470001  3829000  53015300  
2019-01-02  150.880005  4.155  150.990005  2948200  58576700  
2019-01-03  149.490005  4.325  152.600006  1503000  74820200  
2019-01-04  151.740005  4.585  152.339996  2020700  74709300

> df2
           Adj Close              Close              High               Low  \
                GBTC         TLT   GBTC         TLT  GBTC         TLT  GBTC   
Date                                                                          
2018-12-31     3.965  116.845848  3.965  121.510002  4.15  121.559998  3.95   
2019-01-02     4.620  117.461304  4.620  122.150002  4.65  122.160004  4.13   
2019-01-03     4.520  118.797966  4.520  123.540001  4.62  123.860001  4.32   
2019-01-04     4.530  117.422844  4.530  122.110001  4.65  122.559998  4.41   

                         Open               Volume            
                   TLT   GBTC         TLT     GBTC       TLT  
Date                                                          
2018-12-31  120.459999  4.140  120.650002  3829000  17409000  
2019-01-02  121.339996  4.155  121.660004  2948200  19841500  
2019-01-03  122.230003  4.325  122.290001  1503000  21187000  
2019-01-04  121.650002  4.585  122.339996  2020700  12970200
```

Both `df1` and `df2` contain the column of `GBTC`.

How can I merge `df1` and `df2` into a new dataframe that has the following contents?

```
> df3
           Adj Close                          Close                          \
                GBTC         QQQ         TLT   GBTC         QQQ         TLT   
Date                                                                          
2018-12-31     3.965  152.132996  116.845848  3.965  154.259995  121.510002   
2019-01-02     4.620  152.744461  117.461304  4.620  154.880005  122.150002   
2019-01-03     4.520  147.754257  118.797966  4.520  149.820007  123.540001   
2019-01-04     4.530  154.075851  117.422844  4.530  156.229996  122.110001   

            High                           Low                           Open  \
            GBTC         QQQ         TLT  GBTC         QQQ         TLT   GBTC   
Date                                                                            
2018-12-31  4.15  154.979996  121.559998  3.95  152.710007  120.459999  4.140   
2019-01-02  4.65  155.750000  122.160004  4.13  150.880005  121.339996  4.155   
2019-01-03  4.62  153.259995  123.860001  4.32  149.490005  122.230003  4.325   
2019-01-04  4.65  157.000000  122.559998  4.41  151.740005  121.650002  4.585   

                                     Volume                      
                   QQQ         TLT     GBTC       QQQ       TLT  
Date                                                             
2018-12-31  154.470001  120.650002  3829000  53015300  17409000  
2019-01-02  150.990005  121.660004  2948200  58576700  19841500  
2019-01-03  152.600006  122.290001  1503000  74820200  21187000  
2019-01-04  152.339996  122.339996  2020700  74709300  12970200
```

I might have more than one overlapping columns.

It seems that [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is not able to achieve my goal.

Comment: Why would you want to merge on the `GBTC`  column and not on the index ?

Comment: does both dfs have same index like you show?

Comment: No, sometimes the `df`s might have different indices.

Comment: Hmm, can you try `df1.merge(df2).sort_index(axis=1)` ?

Comment: @arhr, Because I want to use `yfinance` to download the prices of some new tickers. Then merge the downloaded DataFrame into my existing DataFrame.

I've already downloaded the prices of some tickers. Now I would like to merge new DataFrame into the old DataFrame.

Comment: Well if you don't have the same indices, even when merging the data on the `GBTC`, you won't have matches

Comment: After running `df3 = df1.merge(df2).sort_index(axis=1)`, the value of `df3.index` becomes `Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')`. This is not something I want.

Comment: I can run `df3.index = df1.index` to get the correct index. However, this only works when the index of `df1` and `df2` are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `unstack()` so that you have two data frames to do a `merge()`
- pick new values from *df2* as preference
- reshape back with `pivot()`

```
dfm = pd.merge(df1.unstack().to_frame().reset_index(), df2.unstack().to_frame().reset_index(), on=["level_0","level_1","Date"],how="outer")
(dfm.assign(**{"0_y":dfm["0_y"].fillna(dfm["0_x"])})
 .drop(columns="0_x")
 .rename(columns={"0_y":0})
 .pivot(index=["level_0","level_1"], columns="Date", values=0).T
)
```

| Date | ('Adj Close', 'GBTC') | ('Adj Close', 'QQQ') | ('Adj Close', 'TLT') | ('Close', 'GBTC') | ('Close', 'QQQ') | ('Close', 'TLT') | ('High', 'GBTC') | ('High', 'QQQ') | ('High', 'TLT') | ('Low', 'GBTC') | ('Low', 'QQQ') | ('Low', 'TLT') | ('Open', 'GBTC') | ('Open', 'QQQ') | ('Open', 'TLT') | ('Volume', 'GBTC') | ('Volume', 'QQQ') | ('Volume', 'TLT') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 4.62 | 152.744 | 117.461 | 4.62 | 154.88 | 122.15 | 4.65 | 155.75 | 122.16 | 4.13 | 150.88 | 121.34 | 4.155 | 150.99 | 121.66 | 2.9482e+06 | 5.85767e+07 | 1.98415e+07 |
| 2019-01-03 00:00:00 | 4.52 | 147.754 | 118.798 | 4.52 | 149.82 | 123.54 | 4.62 | 153.26 | 123.86 | 4.32 | 149.49 | 122.23 | 4.325 | 152.6 | 122.29 | 1.503e+06 | 7.48202e+07 | 2.1187e+07 |
| 2019-01-04 00:00:00 | 4.53 | 154.076 | 117.423 | 4.53 | 156.23 | 122.11 | 4.65 | 157 | 122.56 | 4.41 | 151.74 | 121.65 | 4.585 | 152.34 | 122.34 | 2.0207e+06 | 7.47093e+07 | 1.29702e+07 |